# When to use JSON[] instead of JSON?

Tags: sql, json, database, postgresql, database-design

Say I'm inserting an array of JSON objects into Postgres, for example:

```
[{ s: 'hi', a: true, b: false }, { s: 'bye', a: false, b: true }]
```

I can either do:

```
create table test(a json);
insert into test values ('[{ "s": "hi", "a": true, "b": false }, { "s": "bye", "a": false, "b": true }]');
```

or

```
create table test2(a json[]);
insert into test2 values (array['{ "s": "hi", "a": true, "b": false }', '{ "s": "bye", "a": false, "b": true }']::json[]);
```

what are the advantages/disadvantages of either approach?

Comment: Never. I can't see any advantages of json[].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not ever mix the two.

1. There is a small space and dereferencing overhead with `jsonb`.
2. There is a large space overhead and a small deferencing overhead with `ARRAY`
3. There is a larger overhead in space, and even larger overhead in dereferencing with `JSON[]` (detriments compound).

Not to mention, you'll have two sets of operators and it will be confusing as hell.

Also, don't use `JSON` unless you know when to use `JSON`. You almost always want `JSONB`. To the point that I wouldn't even worry about the corner cases.